# SharePoint 2013: Ho do I get the Total number of Documents in Multiple Document Libraries

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint 2013 with Team Site and four(4) Sub-sites. Each of the sub-sites have one(1) Document Library.

I will to create something like Dashboard on the Team Site Home page where the Total number of documents in each of the Document Libraries can be displayed.

I want this Dashboard to be updated automatically whenever documents are either added or removed.

Please guide me on how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Because of performance , the best way is to calculate count of items in client.
you can call counter function for every list like below code.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CountListItems, "sp.js");

var clientContext = null;
var web = null;


function CountListItems()
{

clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

web = clientContext.get_web();

var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("mydocumnets");

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

var qry = "<View><Query><Where></Where></Query></View>";

camlQuery.set_viewXml(qry);

this.listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(listItems, 'Include(Title)');

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailed));

}

function onSuccess(sender, args) {

alert(this.listItems.get_count());

}

function onFailed(sender, args) {
alert('request failed ');
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Mahdi, it worked! however, am faced with another challenge. I have an empty "div" (say : div class="count") on my SharePoint Home Page where I would like to output the count. Can you please guide me on how to make this happen?

Comment: Oh, yes, in onSuccess function you can access to result. you can iterate in this.listItems collection and generate your html , then place it in your div . for example document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = 'your desire html';

Comment: I tried this: function onSuccess(sender, args) {
document.getElementById('id name').innerHTML =
 this.listItems.get_count();
} and it returned an error saying "cannot set property 'InnerHTML' of null". Any idea on what I need to do to get this thing to work? I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Hi Mandi,

I have checked the link, the script ran as expected.Please note that am able to manipulate div content in my SharePoint environment using either pure JS or jQuery with out any problem.      The issue am having is peculiar to the 'function onSuccess...' I need to be able to output the result of that function to a special div which I have created on the SharePoint home page.

Every attempt to do this using pure JavaScript returned an error saying: cannot set property InnerHTML of null.